# sql/mysql Multiple results from one value

Tags: mysql, sql

I am working on an integration output report to feed into a purchase order system.
All of the possible items are straightforward except for one particular item, which has to be broke out into multiple components.

The current code:

```
select concat("M", id) as ID,  MaterialId, quantity, uom, 
crew_job.JobSubNbr, crew_job.EmployeeId, crewjob_schedule_actual.startTime
from crewjob_material_actual
inner join crew_job on crewjob_material_actual.crew_job_id = crew_job.crew_job_id
inner join crewjob_schedule_actual on 
crewjob_material_actual.crew_job_id = crewjob_schedule_actual.crew_job_id
```

And the current results output:

[image]

What I need to do is something of the effect of (and this is in plain English)

> IF "MaterialID" = '3'
>   THEN [the results should be] show me 3 rows of data such as:
>
> ID = MZ4931, MaterialID = 100, Qty = 0.25, UOM = 1 .... (all else the
>   same)
>
> ID = MZ4932, MaterialID = 101, Qty = 0.50, UOM = 1 .... (all
>   else the same)
>
> ID = MZ4933, MaterialID = 102, Qty = 0.33, UOM = 2
>   .... (all else the same)

Essential, item #3 is a "combined item" that I need to apply based on a standard ratio, where 1 unit of Item 3 is equal to .25 of item 100, .50 of item 101, and 0.33 of item 102. I'm sure this isn't too difficult but I was having a hard time searching.

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: can you please provide sample data and what you want.

Comment: This is MaterialID = 3 only?